# Convert video to bagfile

Tags: video-streaming, ros, bag

I am trying to convert a video to bagfile(.bag). I found this question: [How do I convert a video or a sequence of images to a bag file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31432870/6938984) and implemented the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/38093683/6938984. However when I play it with `rosrun play bagfile.bag` , it gives this error:

> Error: Index entry for topic camera/image_raw contains invalid time. This message will not be loaded.

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to fix it using ROS built-in tools

```
rosbag check
rosbag fix
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Lukashou-AGH. I handled chancing stamp line as `stamp = rospy.Time.from_sec(time.time())`. It is now not occured. However, the map is empty too like previous situation. Gives: 

> W1216 15:57:10.268883 24281 map-builder-flow.cc:101] Map is empty; nothing will be saved.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I suggest you to fix rosbag or record it again, because otherwise you have to deal with this issue in code of all nodes you are using, in this case I assume it's a _map_server_.