# Convert mp4 into .bag file

Tags: computer-vision, ros, video-processing, data-conversion, rosbag

I'm currently working with computer vision systems and I was just wondering if it is possible to convert .mp4 (or any other type of video format) into .bag files.

I've tried some topics and solutions online but so far none of them were successful.

Thank you!

Comment: ".bag" is probably ROS "bag". look into ROS. http://wiki.ros.org/Bags

Comment: You need to be more specific into what you want. Do you want a ROS bag file with a video stream from the mp4?

Comment: @SabrinaAmorim Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38093683) answer your question? otherwise you can use`video_stream_opencv` [package](http://wiki.ros.org/video_stream_opencv)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a video or a sequence of images to a bag file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432870/how-do-i-convert-a-video-or-a-sequence-of-images-to-a-bag-file)